# PHP, How to get current date in certain format

Tags: php

2011-03-04 21:00:40

I want to get current date and time in the above format.  How do I do this in PHP?

Comment: Googling "php date format" brings up http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php as the first hit

Comment: [Overview of PHP date/time functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php)

Comment: From which value do you want to convert? Actual date? Stored value in some variable?

Comment: Below All three giving same answer and getting upvote.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`. See [the manual](http://www.php.net/date) for more.

Answer (score 18):

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // This should do it.
```

Answer (score 11):

I belive the answer is:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```