# Best way to cut string in PHP

Tags: php, string, function, substr

I don't want to know how to use `substr`, there are many examples. But I want to know if it is the best way to short a string? Is there a better/more professional way to do this?

For example, this is what my print_r gives me. But I only need houres and minutes.

```
 string(25) "2020-03-05T12:00:00+01:00"
```

Comment: it would be better for you to format that datetime then to work with it as a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP, How to get current date in certain format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206829/php-how-to-get-current-date-in-certain-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this piece of code :

```
<?php

$time = "2020-03-05T12:00:00+01:00";
$dt = new DateTime($time);
echo $dt->format('H:i');
```

Doing this allows you for many advantages. You can, for instance, manipulate dates more easily (adding, substracting time intervals...) and format the result the same way.